# A method that returns the diffrence between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I must select records which the diffrent between their dates is one day.

So I wrote this conditon in my query

```
DATEPART(year,C1.dtae_cmd) = DATEPART (year,C2.dtae_cmd)
 and DATEPART(MONTH,C1.dtae_cmd) = DATEPART (MONTH,C2.dtae_cmd)
 and DATEDIFF(day,C1.dtae_cmd,C2.dtae_cmd) = 1
```

Isn't their any other method? because this method I use is too long

Answer (score 2):

`DATEDIFF(day,C1.dtae_cmd,C2.dtae_cmd) = 1` should be all you need. Datediff will return the # of days separating the two dates when using days as your frequency.